# How to set word_order=2 when combining 2 evaluation metrics to use?

Tags: huggingface-evaluate, chrf

I use the `evaluate` library to evaluate the translation ability with the following codes with BLEU and chrF:

```
import evaluate

metric = evaluate.combine(
    ["sacrebleu", "chrf"], force_prefix=True
)
```

How can I apply chrF++ (`word_order=2`) using this approach?

In individual metric calls, there is a parameter called `word_order`, like this:

```
chrf = evaluate.load("chrf")
chrf_score = chrf.compute(predictions=[input_sentence], references=[reference], word_order=2, lowercase=True)
```